# Reducing length of division and subdivision tics on ArcGIS Pro scale bar?

Tags: arcgis-pro, scale-bar

Using ArcGIS Pro 1.3.1 I have created a scale bar using the Scale Line 1 Metric template with a few modifications like:

- Show one division before zero
- Divisons: 11
- Subdivisions: 10
- Label Position: Below center
- Label: KILOMETRES

It appears as below:

[image]

How can I make the division and subdivision tics (circled above) be only half as long as they currently are?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should look at the [Symbol effects](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/mapping/symbols-and-styles/symbol-effects.htm).

1. Go to the properties Scale bar.
2. Choose Subdivision marks.
3. Switch to the Properties tab.
4. Click the Structure icon.
5. Click Add Effect and choose Cut.
6. Click the Symbol tab.
7. Under the Cut effect section, adjust your begin and end value as needed.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

After applying the cut effect:

With 3 pt:

[image]

With 1.5 pt:

[image]